# How to get "List of all Spaces" in Blender with Python

Tags: python, workspaces, keymap

I want to let user change the "keymap space" at real time.

[image]

I know,

```py
bpy.data.window_managers['WinMan'].windows[0].screen.areas
```

Which gives the list of open areas, not all.

And, All are present in [`bpy.types.Space`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Space.html#space-bpy-struct) (as Subclasses)

But don't know how to get them as list...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This script should work:

```
import bpy

for area_type in bpy.types.Area.bl_rna.properties['type'].enum_items:
    print(area_type.name, "=>", area_type.identifier)
```

It will give you this output:

[image]

Comment: I thought that `bl_rna` only works with `bpy.ops`. Good to know, `bl_rna` always use `bpy.types` under the hood.
Thanks for your answer.